# show a specific image as watermark background on my blade.php? Laravel

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I want to make a watermark on a specific page on my project.

I write this in app.css

```
.watermarked {
  position: relative;
}

.watermarked:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-image: url("../images/SystemLogo.png");
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  background-position: 30px 30px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

and this is my blade

```
@extends('layouts1.index')

@section('content')

<div class="container">
  <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

  <body>
    <div class="watermarked">
  <div class="text-center">

     <h2 class="text-center"> Appri=oval report </h2>
      <form method="post" action="/student/share-approval/{{$approval->uniid}}">
         @csrf
<p lang="ar" dir="rtl">
  // here is the  approval report 
</p>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">share the report </button>
</div>
</div>
       </body>
    </form>
  </div>
@endsection
```

The problem is not showing the watermark as the image I want .. the result is a default background.  How can I show the image as a background?

Answer (score 0):

I think your HTML is formatted incorrectly. The ending form tag and div is below the body tag.

**Try this:**

```css
.watermarked {
  position: relative;
}

.watermarked:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-image: url("https://en.opensuse.org/images/4/49/Amarok-logo-small.png");
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  background-position: 30px 30px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<div class="watermarked">
  <div class="text-center">
    <h2 class="text-center">Stuff here</h2>
      <form method="post" action="/#">
      <p>
        A Form here
      </p>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
      </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @shrooq I see it. Takes a sec to load. The image is a wolf icon repeated.